# SSRS deployed report not displaying data

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse

I have a report build on the top of SSAS cube, i can view the retrieved data on the query designer while making the dataset, but after deploying the report it take too long to render 
please help

Comment: Could be a number of things ... be more specific ?   Are you embedding the query in SSRS report or using a stored procedure ?  # of rows returning from dataset in query designer ?   Where is sorting applied ?  Query or stored procedure.

Comment: i'm just using a connection for ssas and then by query builder i drag and drop fields